# Python 2.7 Server does nothing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

```
import socket
host = None #will determine your available interfaces and assign this dynamically
port = 5001 #just choose a number > 5000
for socket_information in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
    (family, type, prototype, name, socket_address) = socket_information
sock = socket.socket(family, type, prototype)
sock.bind(socket_address)
max_clients = 1
sock.listen(max_clients)
connection, address = sock.accept()
print 'Client has connected:', address
connection.send('Goodbye!')
connection.close()
```

This is just some example code I used to test connection, and it does nothing. No error, it just sits there forever. I've waited a few minutes now and nothing. I'm on windows.

Comment: its just waiting for a connection ...

Comment: Have you tried connecting to this server ?